# Create Jpeg from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am getting images from sever using this :

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             completionBlock(YES, data);
         }
         else
         {
             completionBlock(NO, nil);
         }
     }];
}
```

Which provide me NSData . Now for better performance i would like to present the image in `jpeg`.

I know how to convert `NSData to UIImag`e, with `UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];`
And how to create NSData from image `NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`

But both are not do what i need, i would like to take that NSData i get from the server, and create out of it JPEG image . how would i do that ?
(do i have to create first a **new** data with jpeg ,than the image from this data? )

Comment: what do you want to achieve? displaying UIImage from jpeg-data you get from the server or converting the server data to some jpeg-data? As for displaying [UIImage imageWithData:] does work with jpeg data. For getting jpeg data from UIImage use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality)

Comment: I am getting png and jpeg, and i think to get a better performance i would take them all, and convert to jpeg, with some compression of 0.75

Comment: I don't want to state the obvious but have you noticed a performance issue?

Comment: yes. i am getting warning all the time, and i did everything possible already. i am loading in another thread, i am loading lazy and smart, i am cleaning things. but i still get warning because of the images that on screen. i just can't get rid of this .

Comment: @Curnelious Having 10 images that each take up 1/10 of the screen is no different than having 1 image that takes up the entire screen. The memory used should be almost exactly the same (with some slight overhead for the objects themselves) and is well within iOS device memory constraints. If you are getting low memory warnings, you should be doing instruments tests to determine where the issue lies.

Comment: Also, note that your desire to use JPGs may be a source of premature optimization. The only advantage JPGs have over PNGs is amount of space that they take _in storage_. Once they are loaded into memory, they will both take exactly the same memory and that memory is completely predictable. Assuming a 32-bit image, the number of bytes it will take up in memory is `w x h x 4`.

Answer (score 3):

To convert the data you get from the server to jpeg, use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:serverData];
NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75f);
```

Comment: That should work. but that will work. It will require that the image, it's NSData, and it's JPEG data all be in memory at the same time though. There are probably CGImage calls to do the same thing using data providers that don't keep multiple copies of the image data in memory, but they are much harder to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

you need to probably do something like this:

```
CGDataProviderRef imgProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef) data);
CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

make sure to release imgRef and imgProvider

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, you can use `CGImage`, `CGImageDestination` and `CGDataProvider` in order to convert some image data. The following function implementation shows how to do so:

```
import Foundation
import ImageIO
import MobileCoreServices

func convertImageData(_ data: Data) -> Data? {
    guard let provider = CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData) else {
        print("Could not create data provider from data")
        return nil
    }

    guard let cgImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: provider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent) else {
        print("Could not create cgImage from provider")
        return nil
    }

    let data = NSMutableData()
    guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data as CFMutableData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) else {
        print("Could not create an image destination from url")
        return nil
    }

    let options = [
        kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: 0.75, // Compress quality (if required)
        kCGImagePropertyOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.right.rawValue // Rotate image to the right (if required)
    ] as CFDictionary

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, options)
    let imageIsWritten = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)

    if !imageIsWritten {
        print("Image could not be written")
        return nil
    }

    return data as Data
}
```

Usage:

```
let data: Data = …
let newData = convertImageData(data)
```

---

As an alternative, you can use `CGImage`, `CGImageDestination` and `CGDataProvider` in order to write some JPEG image data to a given `URL`. The following function implementation shows how to do so:

```
import Foundation
import ImageIO
import MobileCoreServices

func saveImageData(_ data: Data, to fileUrl: URL) {
    guard let provider = CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData) else {
        print("Could not create data provider from data")
        return
    }

    guard let cgImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: provider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent) else {
        print("Could not create cgImage from provider")
        return
    }

    guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(fileUrl as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) else {
        print("Could not create an image destination from url")
        return
    }

    let options = [
        kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: 0.75, // Compress quality (if required)
        kCGImagePropertyOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.right.rawValue // Rotate image to the right (if required)
    ] as CFDictionary

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, options)
    let imageIsWritten = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)

    if !imageIsWritten {
        print("Image could not be written")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let data: Data = …
let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("image.jpeg")
saveImageData(data, to: fileUrl)
```

---

Sources:

- [Image I/O Programming Guide - Working with Image Destinations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/ikpg_dest/ikpg_dest.html)
- [Thinking about Memory: Converting UIImage to Data in Swift](https://bencoding.com/2017/03/07/thinking-about-memory-converting-uiimage-to-data-in-swift/)